# Issue with Android MAUI .net picker - picker keeps reappearing

Tags: c#, maui

Im trying to make a Android app using visual studio and MAUI
.
I have this XAML that display rows of data fetched from a mySQL DB, but I have a issue with the picker.
When I first select a number in any of the pickers, it works fine and the picker selection closes and displays the selected number.
And then if I open one of the other pickers ABOVE the first one it still works fine, but if I open a picker selection from one of the picker below, and select a number - it then shows the selected number as usual, but the picker selection window keeps reappearing again and again until i click Cancel, aslo it then shows back up no matter where I click in the rows (does not show up if I click outside of the listview)

I have tried alot of different things for hours, properly something real easy, but this is my first time trying out XAML and im hoping someone spots my error.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" RowHeight="100">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Height="100">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="100"  />
                        
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" WidthRequest="80" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Description}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ArticleNumber}" />

                <Picker x:Name="{Binding ArticleNumber}" Grid.Column="3" BackgroundColor="LightGray" FontSize="16" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TitleColor="Black" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  Title="Velg antall" TextColor="Black"
                        SelectedIndexChanged="OnQuantityPickerSelectedIndexChanged">
                            <Picker.Items>
                                <x:String>1</x:String>
                                <x:String>2</x:String>
                                <x:String>3</x:String>
                                <x:String>4</x:String>
                                <x:String>5</x:String>
                            </Picker.Items>
                        </Picker>
                    
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Please show the code for your event handler

Comment: Have not setup any event handling yet, my though was that since the issue does not occur all the time, it has nothing to do with the event handler.

Comment: You have a handler assigned - OnQuantityPickerSelectedIndexChanged

Comment: Remove `x:Name="{Binding ArticleNumber}"`. Does the problem go away? First time I've seen anyone Bind to an `x:Name`. What are you attempting to do by binding to `x:Name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be replicated on my side. To fix the picker selection window keeps popping up, you can use [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/?view=net-maui-7.0) as an alternative solution for now. There seems to be a focus issue when using `Picker` inside a `ListView`.

Here's the **XAML** code below for your reference:

```
    <CollectionView x:Name="listView" > 

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                    <Grid>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <RowDefinition Height="100"  />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" WidthRequest="80" />

                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Description}" />

                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ArticleNumber}" />



                        <Picker Grid.Column="3" BackgroundColor="LightGray" FontSize="16" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TitleColor="Black" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  Title="Velg antall" TextColor="Black"
 
                         >
                            <Picker.Items>

                                <x:String>1</x:String>

                                <x:String>2</x:String>

                                <x:String>3</x:String>

                                <x:String>4</x:String>

                                <x:String>5</x:String>

                            </Picker.Items>

                        </Picker>

                    </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    </CollectionView>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! As you said, that fixes it