# .Net Maui Picker keeps reappearing after I select an item and tap anywhere else on screen

Tags: xaml, maui

Here is the code, it is a simple picker and works well on latest versions of Android, but on 7.1 it bugs out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
             x:Class="Views.Picker">
    <ContentPage.Content >
        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="25, 15">
            <Label Text="Device Picker" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

            <Grid>
                <Picker Grid.Column="0" SelectedItem="Dev" Margin="0,15,0,15" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="40">
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>Dev</x:String>
                        <x:String>Testing</x:String>
                        <x:String>Training</x:String>
                        <x:String>Production</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>

                <Image Source="small_down_arrow.png" 
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       x:Name="devicePicker"
                       WidthRequest="15" 
                       HeightRequest="15" 
                       HorizontalOptions="End"
                       Margin="0,0,6,0"
                   >
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Below is an example of what is happening.

[image]

The closest issue I could find was this one:

[Issue with Android MAUI .net picker - picker keeps reappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75344548/issue-with-android-maui-net-picker-picker-keeps-reappearing)

But in this case it he solved it by placing the picker in a CollectionView. Which as you can see in the code above will not work for me.

Comment: Is that all the xaml code shown in your `ContentPage`? If not, could you please share the whole xaml code in your `ContentPage` ? Thanks!

Comment: This seems like focus issue to me.

Comment: I assumed the same thing but even when I try and unfocus the Picker it reappears as well, unless I am doing it incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so seems the issue is this piece of code below, which I added at the very beginning of the project. I added it so that the Soft keyboard would not persist when a person navigate to a new page after they entered info for an input. I added it to Android on MainActivity.cs, removing the code fixes the issue but returns the persistent Soft Keyboard after navigation and input change.

```
public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    var view = CurrentFocus;

    if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
    {

        if (view is EditText editText)
        {
            editText.ClearFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(view.WindowToken, 0);
        }
    }

    return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late but I was having a similar issue but I found a work around kind of

```
<Frame 
  CornerRadius="10"
  HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Center"
  Margin="0, 30, 0, 0"
  Background="transparent"
  Padding="0, 0, 5, 0"
  BorderColor="Transparent"
  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="12"
                            >
  <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapPickSpecies_Tapped"/>
  </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            
  <StackLayout>
       <Label Text="Species Type" Margin="3,0,0,0" FontSize="18"  
           FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="OpenSansSemibold"/>

       <Picker 
           x:Name="pickSpeciesType"
           HorizontalOptions="Fill"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           Background="transparent"
           Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"
           CharacterSpacing="1.5"
           Title="Select a Species Type"
           FontSize="16"
           FontFamily="OpenSansSemibold"                             
           SelectedIndexChanged="pickSpeciesType_SelectedIndexChanged"
           ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding speciesTypeDescription}"
        >
                                    
      </Picker>
  </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

I had my picker inside a frame at the time and any button presses would open the picker right after my button did its job.

So my solution was this:

1 . Any time my button is clicked, the click event would set 
`pickSpeciesType.IsEnabled = false` - This will disable the picker.

```
private void btnAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   pickSpeciesType.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

2 . Then I add a tap geasture as seen in the code block to the frame, so when the user needs to change the picker value, they just tap the frame/label and the tap event would run this:

```
private void TapPickSpecies_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
   pickSpeciesType.IsEnabled = true;
   pickSpeciesType.Focus();
}
```

This will first enable the picker then open it.

Hope this can help someone too

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `Picker` is occupying the other area of the screen, it keeps reappearing after tapping the redundant space on screen. To fix the potential issue, you can try to set the `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` of the `Picker` like below:

```
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
             x:Class="Views.Picker">
    <ContentPage.Content >
        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="25, 15">
            <Label Text="Device Picker" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

            <Grid>
                <Picker Grid.Column="0" SelectedItem="Dev" Margin="0,15,0,15" WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="Red">
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>Dev</x:String>
                        <x:String>Testing</x:String>
                        <x:String>Training</x:String>
                        <x:String>Production</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>

                <Image Source="small_down_arrow.png" 
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       x:Name="devicePicker"
                       WidthRequest="15" 
                       HeightRequest="15" 
                       HorizontalOptions="End"
                       Margin="0,0,6,0"
                   >
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Apologies I did not mean to change the comment, wanted to edit my own question with the full page XAML, is there a way to revert edit?

Comment: @PieterBurger That's fine. I have reverted it.

Comment: As you can notice that I've added `WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="Red"` to the `Picker` and I've tested it on emulator `Android 7.1 - API 25`. The Picker will only appear when clicking the red area. Are you testing it on a real device?

Comment: Thank you. And yes I am testing on both a real device and an emulator, both running Android 7.1 - API 25, I implemented the above as well and same result unfortunately.

Comment: I have added an image to show more or less what happens, with the changes you made as well for better clarity

Comment: @PieterBurger Thanks for your image. As I test it and can't reproduce the issue on emulator Android 7.1 - API 25. This could be a potential issue specifically on Android 7.1 - API 25. I would suggest you can raise [a new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new?assignees=&labels=t%2Fbug&template=bug-report.yml) on Github.

Comment: You can try to replace the `Grid` with `HorizontalStackLayout ` to see if it can fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did this 'hack' to fix the problem. A bit similar to Aaron Maynard approach. I put a button in front of the picker to toggle IsEnabled for the picker.

```
                      <Grid>
                        <Button
                            x:Name="btn"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Clicked="OnButtonClicked"
                            ZIndex="3" />
                        <Picker
                            x:Name="PickerToBeFixed"
                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource RegisterBackground}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding RegisterItems}"
                            SelectedIndexChanged="OnPickerToBeFixedChanged"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                            Visual="Material"
                            ZIndex="2" />
                    </Grid>
```

The code-behind looks like this. Picker.focus() does not work for maui anymore to open the popup (maybe it only ever worked for xamarin). Instead i used a handler with PerformClick().

```
void OnPickerToBeFixedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)(sender as Picker).FindByName("btn");
    btn.IsVisible = true;
    var picker = (Picker)sender;
    picker.IsEnabled = false;
}

void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var picker = (Picker)(sender as Button).FindByName("PickerToBeFixed");
    picker.IsEnabled = true;
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.IsVisible = false;
    var handler = picker.Handler as IPickerHandler;
    handler.PlatformView.PerformClick();

}
```